# Call recording without connection

Tags: iphone, recording, call

I need to record my incoming and outgoing calls on my iPhone 7, but it seems that all third party app use their network to call and record (which requires an internet connection). Is there any way to record a phone call without an internet connection similar to what you can do on Android?

Answer (score 1):

With iOS you are not able to do so as of today.

If your carrier provides support for conference calls (you can speak to two people simulataneously), you can call do the following:

1. **Call your voicemail** so it picks up your call and starts recording.
2. On the iPhone keypad press "**+ add call**" and select the person you want to call.
3. As soon as the other line rings press the "**merge**" button.
4. Inform the person that you are recording him/her.
5. After the call **hang up** on both calls.

If you have enabled Visual Voice Mail (VVM) the recorded conversation will be available as a recording in "**Phone > Voicemail**".

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. To call my voice mail do I need to use another line? I could not active VVM. It returns numeric error code. Any idea about incoming call?